# turing machine show equivalence

Tags: turing-machines

I have a question regarding proofs to show the equivalence of different turing machines and their possible time and space overhead:

I have to show, that a usual deterministic turing machine is equivalent to each of the following:

1. read-only input turing machines, whiche can only write back the symbol it reads
2. turing machines, that have alle tapes (except for the output tape) erased and only blanks when it halts
3. double tape turing machines, where there is no left marker. Instead of that, there are infinitely many blank symbols to both sides.

My suggestions so far:

1. Assuming we only have 0, 1 and blanks, then if we read 0 we write 0 and go right. If we read 1 we write 1 and go right and when we read a blank we halt. No time and space overhead. Would that be right?
2. Before the halting state, we have to insert another state which goes to the left beginning and then writes only blanks while going right. If then there is a blank, it halts. Time over head would be O(n) i think and no space overhead.
3. No idea for this one.

Maybe anyone could help me with this. Thank you very much.

Comment: In your first example, you've shown that there exists a TM that can replicate the behaviour of the read-only machine, but can you replicate the behaviour of an arbitrary TM with a read-only machine?

Comment: Oh I showed only one direction. But how is it possible to show the opposite? A read-only machine cannot write something, which an arbitrary TM can?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that it actually can't, unless there's something not mentioned in the question.